# Why do write attempts to /system/priv-app cause /system to switch to read-only?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, file-system, lineageos, system-apps, file-permissions

I'm trying to write files to the /system/priv-app directory. I boot into recovery (TWRP) and run adb shell.

```
~ # mount /system
~ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,seclabel)
...
/dev/block/mmcblkXXXX on /system type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

I can then run:

```
~ # mkdir /system/tmp
~ # touch /system/tmp/test
```

This works fine: I have no problem modifying /system. (I can also delete things from /system/priv-app.) But if I then try to *write* to /system/priv-app I get the following:

```
~ # mkdir /system/priv-app/test
mkdir: can't create directory '/system/priv-app/test': Read-only file system
~ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,seclabel)
...
/dev/block/mmcblkXXXX on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Now /system is suddenly mounted read-only! Permissions and ownership are identical in /system and /system/priv-app and I'm running as root.

```
~ # ls -al /
...
drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root          4096 Nov 25 07:32 system
~ # ls -al /system
...
drwxr-xr-x   59 root     root          4096 Aug  5  1972 priv-app
```

While in TWRP, SELinux is set to permissive:

```
~ # getenforce
Permissive
```

I'm running Lineage OS 14.1 (Android Nougat) on a Moto G 2015 (aka Moto G3). It's rooted with the official Lineage su addon. I also tried Magisk and get the same result.

I've run out of ideas, and I can't figure out the right search terms, because I've tried a ton of things and have not turned anything up.

How can I enable writing to /system/priv-app?

Comment: Thanks, @IrfanLatif! That worked for me, though I still don't understand how /system gets remounted read-only on the fly. My best guess at this point is some selinux policy that's triggered by writing to priv-app, but I'm at the edge of my knowledge there.

Answer (score 1):

Protecting Android from malicious codes has always been a priority of Google, OEMs and SOC vendors. Even the /system write protection has been [implemented on kernel level](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-TW&u=https://nyllep.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/htc-android-kernel-write-protection/) by some OEMs. And by default, Android mounts `/system` read-only in order to avoid any intentional or accidental changes for [AVB/dm-verity](https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/introduction-to-dm-verity-on-android/) to work properly. Only OTA updates can modify system partition.
However if dm-verity is disabled while rooting the device or when flashing custom kernel/ROM, we can mount `/system read/write` for modifications. But some programs have a built-in code to check if /system is mounted `rw`, and if so, revert the status to `ro`. [Solid Explorer](https://neatbytes.com/solidexplorer/index.php/2015/06/12/root-access-in-solid-explorer/) states:

> If the mount point is mounted in r/o mode it will be temporarily remounted to r/w. After the operation completes (with a success or not), the app mounts the partition back to r/o state.

TWRP has also an option [mount_sys_ro_chk](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/blob/58f2132bc3954fc704787d477500a209eedb8e29/gui/theme/common/languages/en.xml#L271) and by default it mounts /system [read-only](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/blob/android-9.0/partition.cpp#L440).
So the solution is to change the mount point from `/system` to something else as that won't be checked usually.

Another factor that may force `ro` mounting of a partition is Linux kernel's mount option [errors=remount-ro](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). This mount option is usually default on a newly created filesystem:

```
~# tune2fs -l /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system | grep Error
Errors behavior:          Remount read-only
```

So filesystem will be mounted as read-only if an error occurs e.g. `Max Mount Count` is reached and `e2fsck` isn't run. However this is rarely the case on Android. You can view kernel log for any such errors:

```
~# dmesg | grep mount
```

Changing the default behavior is not recommended and can be really harmful:

```
~# mkdir /system-temp
~# mount -o rw,errors=continue /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system-temp
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know some system programs had code to do a check on mount status and change it, if differed from standard.